# St Augustine's saying on redemption

Tags: augustine

I have in my collection of quotes a beautiful saying of St. Augustine in Latin : MORS MORTIS MORTEM MORTI NON VINCISSET, JANUA ETERNA MANCISET CLAUSA  , that is, If the death of death (Jesus )did not conquer death in death, the eternal doors  would have remained closed. Since I have been quoting this saying on different occasions, I would like to know if the saying in Latin is correctly worded and spelt.

Can someone with good knowledge of Latin help ?

Comment: MORTI might need to be MORTE (perhaps) and MANCISET perhaps MANUISSET. And JANUA (door) is singular.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a translation request.

Comment: [Ask in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come to accurately answering this question is by the following: 
MORS MORTIS MORTEM MORTI NON VICISSET, JANUA ETERNI SCRIPSISSET[i] {mancisset[i][um]} CLAUSUM meaning:

If the death of death of Janua(Feast in the Holy Name of Jesus which takes place between January 1st and 6th) is not/has not been conquered, then the (eternal written[scripts/rights/entryway]) would remain locked shut in clausum/a.

I know this may be confusing to understand and read but I spent the last few hours researching my latin notes from the last few years of my latin studying. I have about 4 or 5 years under my belt. It is rather difficult as some of these words I have never experienced. I hope this helps you understand a bit more if it doesn't completely answer you which I'm sure it does not.